# Polymorphic class methods/properties in php?

Tags: php, polymorphism, traits

I was looking into the new PHP 7.x 'Traits' but while they allow pseudo-multiple class type inheritance, I was disappointed to find they cannot be 'use'd conditionally.  I was hoping it might allow for greater class-instance polymorphism.

I'm aware of a couple of ways to emulate polymorphism in just about any semi-object-oriented language without conditional inheritance, but I'm wondering if there are any schemes for doing this I haven't considered in PHP.

Ways I can think of off the top of my head:

- [Conditionally] attach other class instances to a property or property-array in the class.  Drawbacks: properties/arrays holding the instances can become large and you have to write code to check and utilize the property if it is set in the polymorphic class.
- Write multiple behaviors in the class then only execute/enable them conditionally: Drawbacks: classes become overly complex and less modular and you still need extra code to check for the existence/enabling of the behaviors before executing.

Both methods may also be resource intensive (memory, CPU, etc) as well as being hard to trace and involving ugly-complex interactions with the main class.

Use case:
I'm looking at creating a product-builder for an e-commerce website and want to break the properties of the products down into abstracted sub-parts. Some parts may effect the final price of the product, some may add to the final weight of the product, some may effect the size (for shipping) of the product and so on. But some will do none of the above.
I would like to be able to add 'behaviors' when instantiating the sub-component class that defines a product property such as hasPrice, addsWeight, effectsDimensions, etc.  I was hoping I could conditionally use Traits for this, but alas, that is not the case. So I'm probably going to fall back on attaching instances to class properties and checking them conditionally combined with using interfaces to make sure standard methods are available in any behavior-classes so-attached.

I'm just wondering if anyone has any other solutions before I get so far along in building my prototype packages that it's difficult to turn back and rebuild based on a better idea.

Comment: FYI, traits were introduced with PHP 5.4 in March 2012.

Comment: yeah, i was playing with traits. I also finally found the section on morphing in the laravel docs. But I was able to solve most of my problems by re-arranging the object precedence.

Answer (score 0):

well, here's one janky way to do it. (using eval - gaaaahhh!)

```
<?php

require_once("../../vendor/autoload.php");

const TRAITS_NAMESPACE = "OurCompany\\ProductBuilder\\Builder\\Traits";
const CLASS_NAMESPACE = "OurCompany\\ProductBuilder\\Builder\\Components";

if(!function_exists('polymorphic_class')) {
    function polymorphic_class(array $behaviors)
    {
        $classBody = "";
        $classNameParts = [];
        $behaviorUse = sprintf("use %s\\ComponentAbstract;\n", CLASS_NAMESPACE);
        $behaviorInit = "";
        $behaviorCode = "";
        sort($behaviors, SORT_STRING);
        foreach($behaviors as $behavior) {
            switch($behavior) {
                case "Price":
                    array_push($classNameParts, $behavior);
                    $behaviorUse .= sprintf("use %s\\Has%s;\n", TRAITS_NAMESPACE, $behavior);
                    $behaviorInit .= sprintf("        \$this->__has%sInit();\n", $behavior);
                    $behaviorCode .= sprintf("\n    use has%s;\n", $behavior);
                    $behaviorCode .= <<<EOT
    public function setProductPrice(float \$price) { return \$this->setPrice(null, \$price); }
    public function getProductPrice() { return \$this->getPrice(); }
EOT;
                    break;

                case "Size":
                    array_push($classNameParts, $behavior);
                    $behaviorUse .= sprintf("use %s\\Has%s;\n", TRAITS_NAMESPACE, $behavior);
                    $behaviorInit .= sprintf("        \$this->__has%sInit();\n", $behavior);
                    $behaviorCode .= sprintf("\n    use has%s;\n", $behavior);
                    $behaviorCode .= <<<EOT
    public function setProductWidth(float \$width) { return \$this->setWidth(null, \$width); }
    public function getProductWidth() { return \$this->getWidth(); }
    public function setProductLength(float \$length) { return \$this->setLength(null, \$length); }
    public function getProductLength() { return \$this->getLength(); }
    public function setProductHeight(float \$height) { return \$this->setHeight(null, \$height); }
    public function getProductHeight() { return \$this->getHeight(); }
EOT;
                    break;

                case "Weight":
                    array_push($classNameParts, $behavior);
                    $behaviorUse .= sprintf("use %s\\Has%s;\n", TRAITS_NAMESPACE, $behavior);
                    $behaviorInit .= sprintf("        \$this->__has%sInit();\n", $behavior);
                    $behaviorCode .= sprintf("\n    use has%s;\n", $behavior);
                    $behaviorCode .= <<<EOT
    public function setProductWeight(float \$weight) { return \$this->setWeight(null, \$weight); }
    public function getProductWeight() { return \$this->getWeight(); }
EOT;
                    break;
                default:
                    error_log(sprintf("Unknown behavior: '%s'", $behavior));
                    break;
            }
        }
        if(count($classNameParts) > 0) {
            $className = "Generic" . implode("", $classNameParts);
            if(!class_exists(sprintf('%s\\%s', CLASS_NAMESPACE, $className))) {
                $classBody = sprintf("namespace %s;\n\n", CLASS_NAMESPACE)
                    . $behaviorUse
                    . "\nclass " . $className . " extends ComponentAbstract\n{"
                    . $behaviorCode
                    . "\n    public function __construct(\$nameOrSpec=\"Generic " . implode(" ", $classNameParts) . " Component\", string \$version=null)\n"
                    . "    {\n"
                    . "        parent::__construct(\$nameOrSpec, \$version);\n\n"
                    . $behaviorInit
                    . "    }\n}\n";
                //echo $classBody;
                echo "creating class " . $className . PHP_EOL;
                eval($classBody);
            }
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(sprintf("%s - no valid behaviors specified!", __METHOD__));
        }

    }
}

// test all variants of generating classes on the fly

polymorphic_class(['Price']);
polymorphic_class(['Size']);
polymorphic_class(['Size']); // make sure repetition skips trying to redefine
polymorphic_class(['Weight']);
polymorphic_class(['Price', 'Size']);
polymorphic_class(['Price', 'Weight']);
polymorphic_class(['Size', 'Weight']);
polymorphic_class(['Price', 'Size', 'Weight']);

// let's see if they exist now
foreach(['Price', 'Size', 'Weight', 'PriceSize', 'PriceWeight', 'SizeWeight', 'PriceSizeWeight'] as $suff) {
    if(class_exists(CLASS_NAMESPACE.'\\Generic'.$suff))
        echo "Generic".$suff." Exists\n";
}
```

output:

```
creating class GenericPrice
creating class GenericSize
creating class GenericWeight
creating class GenericPriceSize
creating class GenericPriceWeight
creating class GenericSizeWeight
creating class GenericPriceSizeWeight
GenericPrice Exists
GenericSize Exists
GenericWeight Exists
GenericPriceSize Exists
GenericPriceWeight Exists
GenericSizeWeight Exists
GenericPriceSizeWeight Exists

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: then you modify the autoloader to invoke the function to create the class when needed. (just to give some future developer a nervous breakdown when they have to figure out what your code is doing! lol)